# How to get the path of any folder I want when I select them in django

Tags: django, tkinter

I want the user to be able to get the path of any directory so that my code can handle the DICOM images in that directory. Is there any way? I tried using **tkinter** but its window is always showing out before I get on my web.

[image]

Comment: You can not work with Tkinter over a network. It will open a window on the *server* machine, not the client machine.

Comment: so is there any way to get the path of any one directory in django?

Comment: I guess `os` module can handle path of directories. Still not recommended as exposing something from server means security issues will be there.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.